# Creating My Symmetric Key in C#

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

Have been reviewing some symmetric cryptography approaches I've seen a lot of examples that hard code a private static variable in a class, usually something along the lines of:

```
string key = "THISISYOURENCRYPTIONKEY!"
```

and then somewhere further down, the code uses it for encrypting/decrypting.

Putting aside the correct implementation/algorithm/strategy as well as where to store it, I have one simple question. **What should the value of my key be?** I.e. how do I generate it? Most of the examples I see either use some random sentence they just made up, or use a .net class that generates a byte array with a cryptographically secure random number generator that returns byte[]. What do I do with it byte[]? I would assume it shouldn't be a byte array but an actual string that I can save somewhere (and probably not at the top of my class).

Could someone clear up some of the basics for me?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you are encrypting and why. And what's wrong with a byte array?

Comment: Why can't you convert that `byte[]` to a `string`?

Comment: You can convert the `byte[]` array to a base64 string or even just the hex representation of that string. There are a number of ways to turn a byte array into a string.

Comment: Such hard coded keys are only the for test purposes. I really hope no one is using "THISISYOURENCRYPTIONKEY!" as their actual key.

Comment: doesn't the key stay the same always?

Comment: hey so what *would* the value be, instead of THISIS YOURENCRYPTIONKEY! ? I.e. should it be just some random set of characters generated from Rfc2899DeriveBytes? Any examples of what a proper one would look like?

Comment: @user3379785 That "key" is not random enough, so it may be easy to brute force it. If you want to hard code it or not depends on your system architecture. This is too broad to answer it sufficiently. You haven't specified whether this is for data at rest or data in transit. Rule thumb: if you hard code your key then you should keep it somewhere far away from the ciphertexts. Otherwise, it's simple obfuscation.

Comment: data at rest. I was thinking i'll go the random binary data route, and not include a phrase at all.

Comment: You want a secure, random binary key. But how you generate it depends on how you plan to use it. For example, the AES class in .NET has a convenience method to securely generate a key of the correct length for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for symmetric encryption algorithms most often need a binary array as a key. It raises the following questions:

- how to get the binary data for the key?

The key should be random. If it is not random, it is easier to figure out by others. Unfortunately, it is not that trivial to generate random numbers by a computer. Simple random generation algorithms are cyclic, with a quite short cycle, so it is easy find the segment used for key. Sometimes they try to get some input from the real world as a parameter to generate the random, like the time (predictable, not safe) some data from the hard drive, data from network, have the user to type something, etc. These are more or less predictable things. It is also possible to buy devices designed for this purpose, these have a strong algorithm with a very well stored seed value, or they have some kind of particle detector because these particles hit the device randomly. The point is, the key must be unpredictable if it is possible.

- do you need to store the key?

in case of symmetric encryption, the same key is used for encryption and decryption. So if the data is to be decrypted, then the key must be used at least for a second time - so it must be retained somehow. Retaining a key is dangerous, because others might get it. Saving a key to the hard drive? It works for very simple systems, but very easy to find the key. Windows provides [key storage providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and many implementations are available. Simple implementations store the key on the harddrive, but it is encrypted with another key - but of course the key is stored on hardrive otherwise windows wouldn't be able to decrypt the keys for you. It is possible to set up the system in a way that it gets the "main" key during boot, so an administrator must type it, then the key is stored in memory - but the administrator has to remember the "main key", maybe it is written down to a paper in his wallet :) You also can buy devices designed to store keys, these have very sophisticated mechanisms to store the keys safely, using chips designed to do exacly this. These devices usually can do the encryption/decryption, so the key does't have to leave the device - only when it must shared, which is inevitable in case of symmetric algorithms. So it is a large topic, one can spend a fortune to protect the keys, others are just happy using Windows key stores.

People cannot remember 32 byte hexa arrays, this is one of the reason why key derivation algorithms invented. These get an input text and generate pseudo random data from that. Of course, this data is not as secure as a true random key. You can use [rfc2898derivebytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net.

- do you need to use the key many times?

It depends on you use case, but best to avoid using a key many times. Communications protocols agree on a new symmetric key during the handshake and change the key after a while even they are still connected. This is because using the key for long time means that the key is present longer time (means more time to steal it) and produces more data which is a good input to analyze it and try to figure out the key. Also, if you encrypt everything with a single key, it is enough to get a single key to steal all the data. If there are more keys, only part of the data is danger if a key becomes known. One time [pad encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) is the only encryption which cannot be decrypted based on statistical analysis. In that algorithm, every bit of the key is used only once.

Comment: once that pseudo random key is generated, you save it once (and it never changes) right? So same key for all records I encrypt?

Comment: Another question - i'm using Rfc2898DeriveBytes and passing in some simple text like "this is my key" (just as a test). So that works of course but now what? Do I debug and see what the output is for that key, convert to a string, and store THAT as my key?

Comment: @ user3379785, Rfc2898DeriveBytes is for scenarios where you ask the user for password and you generate a key from that password to decrypt the data related to the user. Here, the point is, that you do not store keys, it is the user's responsibility to key his secret safe. In other cases, you generate a binary random data, like 16 or 32 bytes, depending on the algorithm you use, this will be the key, and you try to store this data safely.

Comment: Thanks for this help. Appreciate it. Do you think the IV must be random each time i'm saving data at rest for a user? i.e. if the user has a userid that's a 32 digit unique character, can I use that for the IV each time I encrypt the same data? Or must it be something random? This would produce the same result each time I encrypt a specific string. Is that ok?

Comment: @user3379785: the initial value of the IV doesn't really matter, you can use even zeros. The only important thing is that you must use the same IV for decryption. If you want to hide the fact that you encrypt the same data again and again, it is a simple way to do it with different IV-s, but in this case it is better to salt the plaintext before encryption (and a simple way to do that is to put some random bytes or chars before the real data which you can easily ignore after decryption)